# PHP form required fields error message not shown

Tags: php

Why there's no error message shown in the browser window?
(had more fields but reduced all to a minimum)
There is just nothing happening but that it is redirecting to the 'save_entries.php'.
I would have liked the error message in the table as first row, second column.

The code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors   = array();
    if (empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        $errors['name'] = "Please insert your name!";
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0)
    {
        header("Location: save_entries.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Guestbook</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="save_entries.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <table class="entryForm">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="error">
                    <?php
                    if(isset($errorMeldung['name']))
                        echo $errorMeldung['name'];
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labels">
                    <label for="name">Your Name:
                        <span>*</span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="fields">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                           value="" maxlength="64" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="labels">
                </td>
                <td class="fields">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit button1"
                           value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're storing the error in $errors['name'] but referencing it as $errorMeldung['name']. You should turn on error reporting to catch stuff like that.

Comment: Is the code above the code of `save_entries.php` or is this a different page? If it is a different page, then the reason why "nothing happening but that it is redirecting to the 'save_entries.php'" is that the form is posting to `save_entries.php` and the validation code at the top of this page will not be run.

Comment: @Dave: Sorry, forgot to also change this one into $errors['name']..in real the vars have other names that I shouldn't publish. In the original code they are all the same.

Comment: @Patrick: 'save_entries.php' is the php file where it checks all the spelling (spaces etc.) of all entries before it saves the entries in the array of entries.

Comment: @StefanieGolla You really didn't answer the question. Which I will now pose as two questions. 1.) Is the code given above all contained within the same file or is the PHP in one file and the HTML in another file? 2.) What is the name of the file (or files) shown above? Is the above code from `save_entries.php`?

Comment: @Patrick: so if there is no entry in the array $errors, it should redirect to the 'save_entries.php' file.

Comment: If I delete 'if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {' and the closing '}', then at least it shows the error message BUT not after the 'submit', it shows up at once. (I am very new at php, so sorry if the comments are not perfect!)

Comment: @Patrick: 1) the code above is in one file. 2) the name of the file is 'eintrag_formular_anzeigen.php'

Comment: I've tested your code with Dave's fix and it worked fine. If you did change those variables then the problem isn't in what you posted for code, but elsewhere. Q: Are you running this from your own computer or a hosted site?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I run it from my own computer. It shows up the error messages now but doesnt save the entries in the form anymore. One has to retype it again after one was missing and the error message popped up. New 'new' changed code is below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it :D   (the new code snippets are bold/** **)

```html
<?php
    session_start();

 **$name = "";**
 
   $errors   = array();
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $errors   = array();
            if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
            {
                $errors['name'] = "Please insert your name!";
            }  **else {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                }** 

            if (count($errors) == 0)
            {
//'save_entries.php' gets the post entries, checks them (trim etc.) and save them into an array to give it back to the index.php to show the new guestbook entry with the old ones
                include_once 'save_entries.php';
            }
    }  
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div>
                        <table class="entryForm">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td class="error">
                                        <?php 
                                            foreach ($errors as $error):
                                                echo $error . '<br />';
                                            endforeach;
                                        ?>
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="labels">
                                        <label for="name" class="mandatory">Your Name:
                                            <span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="fields">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text mandatory" value="<?php **echo $name** ?>" maxlength="64" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="labels">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="fields">
                                        <input type="submit" class="submit button1" value="Submit" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are posting the form to `save_entries.php` and therefore the PHP at the top of the file in your question is never being run.  To fix this, change

```
<form action="save_entries.php" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form method="POST">
```

This will make the form post back to the current file, instead of going directly to `save_entries.php`